# JavaFX TableView text in the cells of the columns seems to jump

Tags: java, javafx

When I click the button for showing the pane with the table for the first time (after load) the text in the cells of the columns seems to jump

Maybe it has to do something with the scrollbar that is being added to the table. If I limit the amounts of rows to what can be in the table without the scrollbar the text is not moving when it is being show for the first time. When the table has been show for the first time it is not moving.

Below is example and description on how to reproduce the issue. This is the App.java:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    TableView<TestTable> tableViev;
    ObservableList<TestTable> observableListWithTests;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        this.tableViev = new TableView<>();
        this.observableListWithTests = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        this.tableViev = new TableView<>();
        this.tableViev.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY_ALL_COLUMNS);

        TableColumn<TestTable, Integer> test1 = new TableColumn<>("Test 1");
        TableColumn<TestTable, String> test2 = new TableColumn<>("Test 2");
        TableColumn<TestTable, String> test3 = new TableColumn<>("Test 3");
        TableColumn<TestTable, String> test4 = new TableColumn<>("Test 4");

        test1.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: center; -fx-alignment: center;");
        test2.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: center; -fx-alignment: center;");
        test3.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: center; -fx-alignment: center;");
        test4.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: center; -fx-alignment: center;");

        test1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("test1"));
        test2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("test2"));
        test3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("test3"));
        test4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("test3"));

        for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++) {

            observableListWithTests.add(new TestTable("Test " + x, "Test " + x , "Test " + x, "Test " + x));

        }

        tableViev.getColumns().addAll(test1, test2, test3, test4);
        tableViev.setItems(observableListWithTests);

        VBox centerPane1 = new VBox();
        centerPane1.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 10));
        Text text1 = new Text("CenterPane 1");
        centerPane1.getChildren().add(text1);

        VBox centerPane2 = new VBox();
        centerPane2.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 10));
        centerPane2.getChildren().add(tableViev);

        Button buttonPane1 = new Button("Pane 1");
        Button buttonPane2 = new Button("Pane 2");

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        borderPane.setCenter(centerPane1);

        buttonPane1.setOnAction(event -> borderPane.setCenter(centerPane1));
        buttonPane2.setOnAction(event -> borderPane.setCenter(centerPane2));

        VBox vBoxWithButtons = new VBox();
        vBoxWithButtons.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        vBoxWithButtons.setSpacing(10);
        vBoxWithButtons.getChildren().addAll(buttonPane1, buttonPane2);

        borderPane.setLeft(vBoxWithButtons);
        var scene = new Scene(borderPane, 640, 480);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

And this is the TestTable.java:

```
package org.example;

public class TestTable {

    private String test1;
    private String test2;
    private String test3;
    private String test4;

    public TestTable(String test1, String test2, String test3, String test4) {

        this.test1 = test1;
        this.test2 = test2;
        this.test4 = test3;
        this.test3 = test4;

    }

    public String getTest1() {

        return this.test1;
    }

    public void setTest1(String test) {

        this.test1 = test;

    }

    public String getTest2() {

        return this.test2;
    }

    public void setTest2(String test) {

        this.test2 = test;

    }

    public String getTest4() {

        return this.test4;
    }

    public void setTest4(String test) {

        this.test4 = test;

    }

    public void setTest3(String test) {

        this.test3 = test;

    }

    public String getTest3() {

        return this.test3;

    }

}
```

Open the App, "Pane 1" is showing. Click "Pane 2", pane 2 with the table is showing but the text is moving, its moving fast but enough to notice. Now in the code limit the rows to 10 and redo above -> text is not moving.

I have searched for options on how to always show the scrollbar but I don't think that is possible.
Maybe there is a solution for loading the pane without showing it?

Using OpenJDK 21. JavaFX 21.

**Update**: Below screenshots shows the table before and after the moving:

[image]

[image]

**Update 2**: More screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce. What Java/JavaFX versions are you using?

Comment: OpenJDK 21. JavaFX 21. Question updated with that info.

Comment: I have the same. I am not seeing any movement. Try `centerPane2.applyCSS(); centerPane2.layout();` after adding the table to the pane?

Comment: Its the same with centerPane2.applyCss(); centerPane2.layout(); The content is moving really fast, maybe it is most noticeable in the headline. The issue is not preset when setColumnResizePolicy is not being used, but then I cant get the even alignment (and no extra column) I want.

Comment: Question updated with screenshots.

Comment: (a) Describe "table is moving". (b) I see no difference between your screenshots. (c) I do not notice any "moving" when running your app on a MacBook Pro (Apple Silicon, M1 Pro), Ventura 13.6, Java 21 & JavaFX 21.

Comment: The columns in the header are moving. Look at the screenshots. Is it related to this: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8090112 ?

Comment: @droid You mean the text in the cells of the columns seems to jump to the right several pixels? I am seeing some kind of an animated movement, however brief, at least one out of three runs.

Comment: Yes, or maybe, I'm not sure that "animations" is meant to be there? Updated question with more screenshots and more precise text.

Comment: @droid No, I don't think the text-movement is an intended feature. By "animation" I only meant that there is some quick not-quite-decipherable motion — I am not sure if the column contents are moving, or if the column titles are moving, or both. It seems the TableView is recalculating the layout details, and performing a redraw with different placement.

Comment: I ran this a few times JavaFX 21 and JDK 21.0.1 on OS X (x64).  I couldn't replicate it, but may have less patience than Basil.  So I don't really know.  Perhaps, try it without any custom styling and with a different resize policy.  The resize policy you use was only added to JavaFX recently.  So it may be possible there could be some intermittent bugs in it under certain conditions (which I don't know) or it may have introduced regressions into the entire table layout (less likely).  So also try JavaFX 17, which does not have the resize policy updates.

Comment: No changes when moving css. The issue is not there when no resize policy is being used but then I cant achieve the wanted layout. I think this is a bug when using the resize policy in combination with the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: And same issue with JavaFX 17.

Comment: If it is a bug in the system, then it must be a strange one, which it may be because Basil could replicate something similar.  I tried again a few times and I can't replicate your issue with your code.  JavaFX 17, doesn't have `TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY_ALL_COLUMNS`, it can't be the same, it wouldn't compile or execute on 17.  Maybe you, mean you get the same behavior with 17 and [`CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY)?

Comment: Yes, I know there was a change in the resize policy. Can you see the difference in the screenshots?

Comment: Yes, but I can't replicate it.

Comment: Strange. Running Windows 11 Pro and can also replicate the issue on Windows 10.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this on my local mac. It moves for a while when you click on the button Pane2. It's happening due to column resize. If I comment out that line then it doesn't move.

Comment: If you want  an answer from a reputable source”, ask the [openjfx-dev mailing list](https://mail.openjdk.org/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).

Comment: Thanks jewelsea. I was unsure what to chose as reason. There are many reputable sources here at stack overflow, in this situation the issue is that they are not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @droid I'm in my way to solve this, just one question -> do you want this to be solved without using column resize policy?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I just want the columns to be same size, like what CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY_ALL_COLUMNS gives after the "jumping".

Comment: @droid Can you try setting maxwidth to 50% -> for example: `test1.setMaxWidth( 1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 50 );`

Comment: Not working. Text still jumps.

Comment: Question updated with possible fix to avoid using setColumnResizePolicy.

Comment: @droid, please put fixes in an answer rather than a question edit.

Answer (score 0):

What I want to achieve is just columns with the same size. That is easy using the setColumnResizePolicy, except for the issue with the text jumping.

What I have tried instead, is disabling the setColumnResizePolicy, and using binding for setting the size of the columns, like this:

```
test1.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableView.widthProperty().divide(4));
```

(For all 4 colums).

Above is working fine, except that the horizontal scollbar is being added when there is no use for it:

[image]

So using binding could work for me, if I can disable the horizontal scrollbar, it will not be needed at any time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok to go with width binding approach, then you can try the below approach to hide the horizontal scroll bar. And yes, this will need some extra class/code,. but will help you to have a better control on other things (if required).

The hBar visibility and the other row positioning logic is in the `layoutChildren` method of `VirtualFlow`. So the idea is to tweak some changes for this part of logic in the `layoutChildren` method of `VirtualFlow`. And for this, you need to create a customized VirtualFlow, which eventually leads to creating custom skin and tableView.

So the code will be as simple as :

```
class CustomTableView<K> extends TableView<K> {
    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new CustomTableViewSkin<>(this);
    }
}

class CustomTableViewSkin<T> extends TableViewSkin<T> {
    public CustomTableViewSkin(CustomTableView<T> control) {
        super(control);
    }

    @Override
    protected VirtualFlow<TableRow<T>> createVirtualFlow() {
        return new CustomVirtualFlow<>();
    }
}

class CustomVirtualFlow<T> extends VirtualFlow<TableRow<T>> {
    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        // Set prefHeight to 0 before layoutChildren call, to ignore the scroll bar height in the calculations.
        getHbar().setPrefHeight(0);
        super.layoutChildren();
        // Set visible to false after layoutChildren call, to hide the remaining bits of scroll bar that are still visible.
        getHbar().setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Please check the below updated demo when combining all changes:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableView_NewConstraints_Demo extends Application {

    CustomTableView<TestTable> tableView;
    ObservableList<TestTable> observableListWithTests;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        this.tableView = new CustomTableView<>();
        this.observableListWithTests = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        // this.tableViev.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY_ALL_COLUMNS);

        TableColumn<TestTable, String> test1 = new TableColumn<>("Test 1");
        TableColumn<TestTable, String> test2 = new TableColumn<>("Test 2");
        TableColumn<TestTable, String> test3 = new TableColumn<>("Test 3");
        TableColumn<TestTable, String> test4 = new TableColumn<>("Test 4");

        test1.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: center; -fx-alignment: center;");
        test2.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: center; -fx-alignment: center;");
        test3.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: center; -fx-alignment: center;");
        test4.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: center; -fx-alignment: center;");

        test1.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().test1);
        test2.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().test2);
        test3.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().test3);
        test4.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().test4);

        test1.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableView.widthProperty().divide(4));
        test2.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableView.widthProperty().divide(4));
        test3.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableView.widthProperty().divide(4));
        test4.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableView.widthProperty().divide(4));

        for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
            observableListWithTests.add(new TestTable("Test " + x, "Test " + x, "Test " + x, "Test " + x));
        }

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(test1, test2, test3, test4);
        tableView.setItems(observableListWithTests);

        VBox centerPane1 = new VBox();
        centerPane1.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 10));
        Text text1 = new Text("CenterPane 1");
        centerPane1.getChildren().add(text1);

        VBox centerPane2 = new VBox();
        centerPane2.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 10));
        centerPane2.getChildren().add(tableView);

        Button buttonPane1 = new Button("Pane 1");
        Button buttonPane2 = new Button("Pane 2");

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        borderPane.setCenter(centerPane1);

        buttonPane1.setOnAction(event -> borderPane.setCenter(centerPane1));
        buttonPane2.setOnAction(event -> borderPane.setCenter(centerPane2));

        VBox vBoxWithButtons = new VBox();
        vBoxWithButtons.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        vBoxWithButtons.setSpacing(10);
        vBoxWithButtons.getChildren().addAll(buttonPane1, buttonPane2);

        borderPane.setLeft(vBoxWithButtons);
        var scene = new Scene(borderPane, 640, 480);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    class CustomTableView<K> extends TableView<K> {
        @Override
        protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
            return new CustomTableViewSkin<>(this);
        }
    }

    class CustomTableViewSkin<T> extends TableViewSkin<T> {
        public CustomTableViewSkin(CustomTableView<T> control) {
            super(control);
        }

        @Override
        protected VirtualFlow<TableRow<T>> createVirtualFlow() {
            return new CustomVirtualFlow<>();
        }
    }

    class CustomVirtualFlow<T> extends VirtualFlow<TableRow<T>> {
        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            // Set prefHeight to 0 before layoutChildren call, to ignore the scroll bar height in the calculations.
            getHbar().setPrefHeight(0);
            super.layoutChildren();
            // Set visible to false after layoutChildren call, to hide the remaining bits of scroll bar that are still visible.
            getHbar().setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    class TestTable {
        private StringProperty test1;
        private StringProperty test2;
        private StringProperty test3;
        private StringProperty test4;

        public TestTable(String test1, String test2, String test3, String test4) {
            this.test1 = new SimpleStringProperty(test1);
            this.test2 = new SimpleStringProperty(test2);
            this.test4 = new SimpleStringProperty(test3);
            this.test3 = new SimpleStringProperty(test4);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works overall. One issue is just that when the user is re-sizing the header (the far right), a empty header/column appears on the right.

Comment: Not sure what your exact requirement is. When you resize a column you want the other columns to resize as well or you want to completely turn off manual resizing. This is just a work around. But if you exactly want how it works with resize policies, then you need to look for the exact bug and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on several machines and it could not be reproducible on most of them. However I was able to reproduce it on an older desktop running windows 11. My guess is that this is a timing issue when rendering the data and calculating the constraints. I don't think it is a big issue since it fixes itself whenever you scroll the table or change the view back and forth, but sometimes you got to do what you got to do and therefore I propose the following solution:

Remove the constraint from the table:

```
// this.tableViev.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY_ALL_COLUMNS)
```

When setting the the table on the second button action:

```
buttonPane2.setOnAction(event -> borderPane.setCenter(centerPane2));
```

Replace it with the following:

```
buttonPane2.setOnAction(event -> {
    borderPane.setCenter(centerPane2);
    hackyWayToFixTextJumping();
});
```

Where the new function is:

```
private void hackyWayToFixTextJumping() {
    tableViev.setVisible(false);
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                tableViev.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
                tableViev.setVisible(true);
            });
        }
    };
    long delay = 10L;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, delay);
}
```

You can play around with the delay, but if you go 5 or below you can see the problem reproducing randomly again, at least on my machine. The reason why we are hiding the table first is to not show the jumping when resizing happens and the separate thread is needed so that it runs independently of the JavaFX thread while waiting for the delay to pass.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It solves the text jumping in 9 out of 10 cases but I still see jumping once in a while, also when using different delays.

Answer (score 0):

Author of the new constrained resize policy here.

Thank you for bringing this up in the OpenJFX mailing list!

Yes, it does work as expected (or as designed).  Is it the best possible user experience, can it be improved by, let's say, figuring out that it does need the vertical scroll bar before resizing the columns?  Possibly.

I've created a JBS ticket bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8329104 to investigate the issue (though we can't promise any dates).

Comment: I believe your answer is more of a comment than an answer since it does not provide a solution to the problem described in the question. I believe that you should not post a comment as an answer simply because you do not yet have enough reputation points, i.e. 50, to post comments.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35837934)

Comment: The answer is that it works as designed.  There is a followup - a JBS ticket that this might be fixed in the OpenJFX mainline.  You may not get a better answer - half of the answers here are actually incorrect.  This also might be my last comment on stackoverflow.  Cheers.